# cobol difference with Picture having a dash (-) and a having a X

Tags: cobol

What are the differences between the 2 pictures below?

PIC X(15)

PIC ----,---,---.99.

Is the bottom just another way to represent the top?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`PIC X(15)` Represents 15 characters of virtually any type of data, could be
digits, letters or any other symbol (printable or not).

`PIC ----,---,---.99` Represents a numeric edited data item capable of holding
values in the range +999999999.99 through -999999999.99. This item will display a leading minus sign if the
value placed into it is negative, otherwise it will display the number without a leading sign. The displayed
number will have comma separators at the indicated positions provided there is at least 1 digit in front of it.

Here are a few samples of the way certain numbers will display:

```
999999999.99 displays as 999,999,999.99
1234.56      displays as       1,234.56
0            displays as            .00
-1234567.12  displays as  -1,234,567.12
-3           displays as          -3.00
```

Variables such as this are for display only. Don't even think
about doing arithmetic with them! Given the following data declarations:

```
01 DISP-NBR   PIC ----,---,---.99.
01 NBR        PIC S9(9)V99.
```

The following `MOVE` operations are both valid

```
MOVE 1234.56 TO NBR
MOVE 1234.56 TO DISP-NBR
```

However,

```
ADD 1 TO NBR
```

is perfectly valid but...

```
ADD 1 TO DISP-NBR
```

Will give you a compile error. Even though `DISP-NBR` contains numeric data it is in a display only
format. You need to do math using data items that are purely numeric and then `MOVE` them to display fields
for 'pretty printing'.

[This table](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IGY3LR31/5.3.12.1?SHELF=&DT=20060329140556&CASE=)
describes all of the `PICTURE` elements that may be used in COBOL and what they are for.

Answer (score 2):

The first one can have any alpha-numeric caracters.

The second one is used to format number. The dash means that if you have a negative number, a dash will be shown beside (at the left) of the number. Only one dash will be displayed. If the number is positive, a space will shown for every dashes.